# Actions - perform() method not working in iOS ionic app on textfields

Tags: java, ios, cordova, selenium, appium

I’m trying to enter data in text fields(username and password). I tried 2 approaches,

```
1. sendkeys(),
```

Issue: it didn’t entered any data but test continued.

```
2. Actions actions = new Actions(driver);  
   actions.moveToElement(element);  
   actions.click();  
   actions.sendKeys(str);  
   actions.build().perform();
```

Issue: perform() threw exception:

```
Method has not yet been implemented 
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)  
    Command duration or timeout: 14 milliseconds
```

OS: iOS 10.3.3
App: cordova app
Java-client: 4.1.2
Appium version: 1.6.5

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. xpath selector for email be:

   ```
   login.input.email=id:Email
   ```
2. tree.setPage("login);

   driver.input("input","email",str); //your input string